# Navbar toggle button not working bootstrap 4.0

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, bootstrap-4

****Here's is my code
im getting started with *bootstrap 4.0*
i even tried to copy code from official documentation but still navbar toggle is not working
i tried current alpha version of bootstrap as well

---

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">tindog</a>
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Downloads</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a JavaScript functionality, you need [Bootstrap.js](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/javascript/). I added the `<script>`-tags and it works now:

```html
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">tindog</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Downloads</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If it solved your problem, then mark the answer as the solution :)